# Accessing database rows within Custom Functions

Tags: function, sqlite

Is it possible to access database (by select, update, insert queries) through C/C++ API, from within custom sqlite functions created through sqlite3_create_function [variants](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html)?

All examples found on internet displays custom functions which manipulate data passed to the function as arguments. Some examples are [here](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/code/myfuncpp.cc.html).

All I want is to execute a select statement within custom function and based on result modify the row through sql update.

Answer (score 0):

The [page you linked to](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) says:

> An application-defined function is permitted to call other SQLite interfaces. However, such calls must not close the database connection nor finalize or reset the prepared statement in which the function is running.

So reading and modifying the database is allowed.
(The [eval extension](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/file?name=ext/misc/eval.c) creates a function that allows to execute any SQL statement recursively.)